# How to set ZIndex on StatusBarItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 'StatusBar' with 'StatusBarItem'`s and one of them is current status label. I want it to fill all available space but dont overlap other Items. Usually I achieve this using ZIndex=-1 but there is no ZIndex on StatusBarItem. So how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that StatusBar derives from ItemsControl, which allows you to set the template for ItemsPanel. It seems like using a different template for that will give you the flexibility you need for layout.